# dynamically adding style doesnt work on IE

Tags: javascript

My function creates an element dynamically and also add style

```
create:function(el,attr,sty_le){
    this.elem=document.createElement(el);

    for(var k in attr){
        if(attr.hasOwnProperty(k)){
            this.elem.setAttribute(k,attr[k]);
        }
    }

    for (var k in sty_le) {
        if (sty_le.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            this.elem.style[k]=sty_le[k];
        }
    }

    return this.elem;
}
```

This seems to work perfectly on *Firefox*, *Chrome* and *Opera* but *Internet Explorer* shows the following error instead:

> Message: Invalid argument.   Line: 20   Char: 5   Code: 0

where line 20 is:

```
this.elem.style[k]=sty_le[k];
```

How can I make it work in IE ?

Comment: Could you show the value of `sty_le` and `k` at the moment of the break?

Comment: bottom :
right : px

ok i guess the problem is right : px 

where px is invalid

Comment: Why are people editing a question from 2013 that is an obvious typo issue. Just close it already